# How do I attached a scroll event to this?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Javascript and I'm a little bit lost right now.

I manage to use some scripts I found to make a full background image slideshow.
I can click on two delimited area to move forward or backward but I want to add a .scroll() event so it moves also when the user scroll.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

You can see it here: http://www.litige-mtl.com/index.php

And you have the code I used here:

```
    var arr = [1,15,25];
      $('#slides').superslides({
        animation: 'fade'
    });
    var links = $(".slides-pagination").children();
      for (i=0; i<links.length;i++) {
        var el = links[i];
        var display = false;
      for (j=0; j<arr.length;j++) {
        if (arr[j] == i+1) {
          display = true;
        }
      }
      if (!display) {
        $(el).remove();
      }
    }
    //false click
    $("#slideMenu p").each(function(i) {
      $(this).click(function() {
        $(".slides-pagination a")[i].click();
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to JavaScript take a look at the onscroll event, you can bind it to the window element. Read through this link: [click me](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

Otherwise i would recommend using jQuery, I think its faster and much easier to code.

Comment: Thank you, I already read this article but don't really understood how to apply it on my specific case.
I don't mind  using JQuery.

Comment: Hmm, there is another topic which tells you how you can detect the scroll direction, you can find it here: [link](http://www.litige-mtl.com/index.php) Do you mange the change of the slideshow on your own?

Comment: I used some piece of code i found online and change it to fit my project.
But now I'm just blocked with this scroll detection and as I don't know how to write script from scratch it starts to be difficult to add a scroll event to that piece of code.